# What is the standard or most frequently used citation style used in law journals?

Tags: legal-writing

For example, most major science journals tend to use APA citation style, whereas most major humanities journals utilize MLA (8th edition I believe is the most recent).

What citation style do most law/legal journals utilize?

On the side, are footnotes permissible in most law journals, or does it depend on the journal?

And I do not believe I could find a hashtag to aptly describe my question, so brainstorming to create a new one would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*The Bluebook: A Uniform System of Citation*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As to footnotes, they are not only permissible, but they may take up one-third to one-half of the page.  Law journal articles are among the most thoroughly sourced articles in academia.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify as to what is said. The Bluebook defines two parallel systems for citation:

1. Journal Citation
2. Legal Citation

The measure of a law journal is how rigorously it conforms to the Bluebook's journal citation standard (one of the reason law journals are regarded as mere deforestation).

Legal citation only uses roman and italic (or underline) fonts. Journal citation uses small capital fonts in addition.

Generally, legal citation is done inline without footnotes. Journal citation is always done with footnotes.